# Dynamically adding component in Angular

Tags: angular

I am pretty new to Angular and trying to build a chatting application. I have a list of all people on the right hand side component (`chatlist.component`). This component has a list of `chatlist-item.component`. I have another component, a `chat-window.component` which is the chat window. I want to open the chatwindow on click of my chatlist-item.

For this, I needed to dynamically add `chat-window.component` on click. For initial testing, I added a button on my home page(`app.component.html`) and used `ComponentFactoryResolver` to dynamically add the component. But for this, I had to use `ViewChild` with `ng-template`.

```
<ng-template #chatcontainer>
            </ng-template>
```

This is working perfectly fine. But I am not able to access this `chatcontainer` in my `chatlist-item` component where I actually want the click to happen.
Here is the link to my work:

[StackBlitz Link to my work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbl4sg)

I am not sure how I can achieve this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Edit**
Please view the preview in the above StackBlitz link in full screen mode, as the chatlist is only visible then, or use the following url
[Link to the preview](https://angular-dbl4sg.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve exactly. The link as is though has an error and it is because your import statement is wrong: `import { ChatWindowComponent } from './chat-window/chat-window.component';` should be `import { ChatWindowComponent } from '../chat-window/chat-window.component';`

Comment: @peinearydevelopment Someone might have changed the link above. I have fixed that error. I want to open the chat window when I click on any of the profile in the chatlist. Can you check the link now.